# With Process PerformanceCounters how do I know what process an instance is associated with?

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

When querying instances for the the "Process" performance counter category there might be multiple instances of of a process with the same name.

For example this code:

```
var cat = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Process");

var names = cat.GetInstanceNames();

foreach (var name in names)
    Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Might print these results:
...
iexplore
iexplore#1
iexplore#2
iexplore#3
...

How do I know which process each of these counter instances corresponds to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a PerformanceCounter named "ID Process" in the "Process" category that will return the pid of the process that the performance counter instance corresponds to.

```
var cat = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Process");

var names = cat.GetInstanceNames();

foreach (var name in names.OrderBy(n => n))
{
    var pidCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "ID Process", name, true);
    var sample = pidCounter.NextSample();
    Console.WriteLine(name + ": " + sample.RawValue);
}
```

This will print:

> ...
>
> iexplore: 548
>
> iexplore#1: 1268
>
> iexplore#2: 4336
>
> ...