# How to get the stats of memory and process consumption of a .net assembly

Tags: .net, performance-testing, performancecounter, perfmon

I  need to capture the statistics of windows service in terms of memory and process usage.
I tried exploring Perfmon, it has options for capturing the system performance. Probably this will have option for monitoring individual process also.

Please let me know how can i monitor windows service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i quickly pulled up the pages which helped me a lot when i started with performance counters

Your reference: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx

Simple Example
[How can I use Performance Counters in C# to monitor 4 processes with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703166/how-can-i-use-performance-counters-in-c-sharp-to-monitor-4-processes-with-the-sa)

Special ASP.Net Counters:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4(v=vs.100).aspx

When you run intro problems read these:

[Performance Counter by Process ID instead of name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115436/performance-counter-by-process-id-instead-of-name)

and

[With Process PerformanceCounters how do I know what process an instance is associated with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679231/with-process-performancecounters-how-do-i-know-what-process-an-instance-is-assoc)

and

http://openrent.blogspot.de/2008/01/multiple-clr-performance-counters.html